# computer freezes after running this code

Tags: python

Why does my computer freeze when running this code?

```
import sys
from scanner import *

def main():
        readTokens("words.txt")

def readTokens(fileName):
        s = Scanner(fileName)
        token = s.readtoken()
        item = []
        while (token != ""):
            item.append(token)
            token = s.readtoken()
        s.close()
        return item

main()
```

Comment: You'll need to reformat that code there a bit. Impossible to read as it is.

Comment: What does `readtoken` do when you're out of tokens? Does it actually return `""`? I doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of that code is never called. Only readTokens() is called.

But without knowledge of "Scanner" code all one can suggest is to place some logging/debug statements into your code to see if it breaks in this code segment or somewhere else.

Comment: Well then the problem is either with your computer or in the Scanner code.